# How do I add tags to the taxonomy data via node and the fields?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I need to store the tags which newly created in the taxonomy_term_data table, and also in the node field. I created the node field as field_beaches_tags (term reference) using "Select list" as widget.

I need to store the value in this and also in the taxonomy term data table with reference vid as the tags. I have the location name field in the form; when I submit the form the location, I must store the tags in the taxonomy table and also in the node field.

```
 function My_beaches_create_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->uid = 1;
    $node->type = 'content_type';
    $node->taxonomy[1] = $values['location_name'];
}
```

1 is the vid of the tags in the taxonomy, but I am able to store the value in the database table.

Answer (score 5):

In drupal 7, Taxonomy terms are attached as regular fields. So `$node->taxonomy` is no longer a standard property that Taxonomy module picks up.

If your field name is `field_beaches_tags`, assign tags to the node as below.

```
$node->field_beaches_tags[$node->language][]['tid'] = 23;
```

Note that the `23` above is the term ID of the taxonomy term. 
If you have an array of terms, you can assign all of them like below:

```
$terms = array(23, 45, 678, 1212);
foreach ($terms as $tid) {
  $node->field_beaches_tags[$node->language][]['tid'] = $tid;
}
```

Keys in the `$node->field_beaches_tags[$node->language]` array will be used as delta values of the field.

#### Create a new taxonomy term

```
$term = new stdClass();
$term->name = ‘My New Term Name’;
$term->vid = 'vocabulary_id'; 
taxonomy_term_save($term);
```

Now, `$term->tid` will be populated with the new term ID that you can use. 
See [taxonomy_term_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7) for the API doc.

[taxonomy_get_term_by_name()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7) can be used to load terms by a given name.

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('my existing term name', 'beach_terms');
// $term->tid will now be in place.
```

Your overall code can be like the following.

```
$terms_given = array('Miami', 'Colombo', 'Pizza');
$node = new stdClass();
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->type = 'content_type';

foreach ($terms_given as $term_name) {
  $terms_matched = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, 'beach_terms'); // "beach_terms" is the machine name of vid 1.
  if ($terms_matched) {
    //We blindly use the first match. Not very elegant.
    $first_term = current($terms_matched);
    $node->field_beaches_tags[$node->language][] = (array) $first_term;
  }
  else {
    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->name = term_name;
    $term->vid = 1; // Vid from the question. 
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
    $node->field_beaches_tags[$node->language][] = (array) $term;
  }
}
```

Comment: if i want to create new tags means what i need to include ayesh this is fine if there is already tag , but in my db tags is vid and tid as 1 what id i need to give , can you explain a bit ayesh

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Tags also we need to do like this ayesh , i need to create tag for every location , every location name as a tag and i need to store in the taxonomy term data

Comment: Small thing - `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()` passes the return from `taxonomy_term_load_multiple()`, which gives an array keyed by the term IDs. So `isset($terms_matched[0]['tid')` will always yield `FALSE`; using `array_shift()` would solve that

Comment: Thanks @Clive - Used current() to get the first array from the return'd array.